# Fullcalendar event id undefined - event click

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'am using fullcalendar and I'm trying to get the id from the fullcalendar calEvent.id that should be an integer or string and I get a message of an undefined id event.

Jquery:

```
$('#calendar1').fullCalendar({

// code

eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        var data = calEvent.start.format();
        alert("remove evento id: "+calEvent.id);
        removeEvento(calEvent.id, data, '#calendar1');            
    }

});
```

Comment: only try `$('#calendar1').fullCalendar({});` is this working? without eventClick.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi everything is working ....adding event and remove in fullcalendar but I need the event id to remove the event from the database

Comment: console.log(calEvent.id) what are you getting?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi  I get a message undefined

Comment: try console(calEvent) what are you getting?

Comment: can you make fiddle for this? problem is something else.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yixjs3erz/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98008/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-pedro).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **id** field is not set properly when you add event.

This will cause not getting back in `eventClick` `function`.

If it get set properly then you will get `calEvent.id` value.

Comment: Yes it is the answer after searching for whole day... I am checking LTEAdmin theme and it uses FullCalendar, where the existent event don't have `id`. If I add `id` manually in the adding event code, remove code `jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);` works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you add an event, it gets a temporary id which is located in `calEvent._id` which is the "internal" id of the event.